# ERROR : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereIn()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a method which returns a list of provinces based on some `join` and `where` clauses. The problem I have is That `laravel` throws an Exception that tells there is an undefined method called `whereIn`. But there exist `whereIn` method in `Eloquent`. How should I use `whereIn` method on joins?

```
public static function getProvinces($IDs = array()){
        $query =
            DB::Table('doctors')
            ->join('users',  function($join){
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'doctors.user_id')
                    ->whereIn('users.status_id', array(3,4,7));

            })
            ->join('contacts',  function($join){
                $join->on('doctors.id', '=', 'contacts.doctor_id')
                    ->where('contacts.type_id', '=', 1);

            })
            ->join('provinces', 'contacts.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
            ->select('contacts.province_id as id','provinces.name as name',DB::raw("COUNT('contacts.province_id') as count"))
            ->groupBy('contacts.province_id');
        if(!empty($IDs))
            $query->whereIn('doctors.id', $IDs);
        return $query->get();

    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *1.* You're not working with Eloquent here, you're working directly with the [QueryBuilder](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html)-class. *2.*: `$join` is not of type QueryBuilder but of type [Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html) which has no `whereIn`-method.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, [JoinClause](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html) doesn't support whereIn method, but you can overwrite it following way:

```
$query =
    DB::Table('doctors')
    ->join('users',  function($join){
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'doctors.user_id')
            ->where('users.status_id', '=', 3)
            ->orWhere('users.status_id', '=', 4)
            ->orWhere('users.status_id', '=', 5);
    })
    ->join('contacts',  function($join){
        $join->on('doctors.id', '=', 'contacts.doctor_id')
            ->where('contacts.type_id', '=', 1);

    })
    ->join('provinces', 'contacts.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
    ->select('contacts.province_id as id','provinces.name as name',DB::raw("COUNT('contacts.province_id') as count"))
    ->groupBy('contacts.province_id');
```

Comment: It would probably be even easier to just put it into the 'global' `where`-clause of the query, like `DB::table(..)->join(..)->whereIn('users.status_id', [3,4,7])->where('contacts.type_id', 1)->select(...);`